# Getting a function's result as jQuery autocomplete options

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I have a function that returns a list of strings that I need to set as options shown in my jQuery autocomplete component. The code looks more or less like this:

```
private static List<string> AutoCompleteOptions(string input)
    {
        var query = (from items in availableItems where items.Contains(input)
                     select items);
        return items;
    }
```

However, the code result I want is not within the service; it's in the client. Is there a way to use this result as the options for my autocomplete component (setting an aspx.cs file at the url field rather than the asmx)?

The code for the autocomplete so far looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Default.aspx.cs/AutoCompleteOptions",
                    data: "{ 'input':'" + request.term + "' }",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

But all I get as a result is a "Not found" message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend has sent me a different approach to my problem. It is a simple enough solution and it doesn't require direct access to the code-behind. Still, it required a couple of changes in my jQuery component as well. 
The component's code ended up looking like this:

```
    $(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: SourceFromControl,
            select: function (e, ui) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#tags').val(ui.item.label);
                $('#tagId').val(ui.item.value);
                console.log(ui.item.value);
            },
            focus: function (e, ui) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#tags').val(ui.item.label);
            },
        });
    });
```

It was also necessary to add an extra asp component which would contain a list with the string array that I wanted to show in the autocomplete component:

```
    <asp:Literal ID="lstSourceFromControl" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

After that, all I needed to do was populate the lstSourceFromControl component with the data I needed, then serialize it by using a StringBuilder. Not as elegant as using a serializer, but it worked just the way I needed it to work!

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script>");
    sb.Append("var SourceFromControl = [");
    string item = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < controle.Length; i++)
    {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
                    item = ",";
            sb.Append(item + "{label:\"" + control[i] + "\"}");
            item = ",";
    }
    sb.Append("];");
    sb.Append("</script>");
```

Nevertheless, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Encode data to json using [JavaScriptSerializer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library)

```
private static List<string> AutoCompleteOptions(string input)
{
    var query = (from items in availableItems where items.Contains(input)
                 select items);
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(items);
}
```

Or you can try this also

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Default.aspx.cs/AutoCompleteOptions",
    data: "{ 'input':'" + request.term + "' }",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {

        data = $.parseJSON(data);

        response(data.d);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```